# Vite + React SPA no funciona en IOS

Tags: reactjs, nginx, vite, spa

Estoy teniendo un problema con mi SPA.
Resulta que está funciona de lo más bien con windows y Android, utilizando chrome como navegador, y en IOS (IPhone) utilizando Safari o Chrome no funciona, ni siquiera renderiza la pagina todo queda en blanco.

Alguno sabe a que se puede deber?

Aclaración: El web server que utilizo es NginX.